# In Micronaut, how do I use plain jdbc row mapping? (kick out ORM-Hibernate)

Tags: jdbc, micronaut-data

How to do plain **jdbc row mapping in Micronaut** ? (kick out ORM-Hibernate)

- a way to do parameterized, prepared statement.
- a custom mapping mechanism.

I want to avoid Hibernate/ORM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you tagged the question with micronaut-data I assume that is what you are using.  Micronaut Data doesn't have to have anything to do with Hibernate.  You can use straight JDBC repositories.  See https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-data/1.0.1/guide/#sql.